# How to replace some rows in 2-D tensors in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is an example of my question.

```
origin_embeddings = tf.constant([[1.1,2.2,3.3], 
                                 [4.4, 5.5, 6.6], 
                                 [7.7, 8.8, 9.9],
                                 [10.10, 11.11, 12.12]]) # 4 * 3

indice_updated_embeddings= tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
                                        [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]) #  2 * 3

indices = tf.constant([1,3], dtype=tf.int32)

new_embeddings = tf.constant([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3],
                          [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], # rows=1, indice_updated_embeddings[0]
                          [7.7, 8.8, 9.9],
                          [4.0, 5.0, 6.0] # rows=3, indice_updated_embeddings[1]
                         ])
```

create a new embeddings matrix consisting of some rows (not in indices) of the origin embeddings, and some rows(in indices) of the updated embeddings.

In Numpy, it is simple to realize the function:

```
origin_embeddings[indices] = indice_updated_embeddings # in-place
new_embeddings = np.put(origin_embeddings, indices, indice_updated_embeddings) # create a new matrix
```

I want something like the 'put' function in numpy.

I have tried the tf.where method, but it is not that easy.

Comment: What version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: version: 1.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using an old version of TensorFlow, you can do that with [`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

origin_embeddings = tf.constant([[ 1.1 ,  2.2 ,  3.3 ], 
                                 [ 4.4 ,  5.5 ,  6.6 ], 
                                 [ 7.7 ,  8.8 ,  9.9 ],
                                 [10.10, 11.11, 12.12]]) # 4 * 3
indice_updated_embeddings= tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
                                        [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]) #  2 * 3
indices = tf.constant([1, 3], dtype=tf.int32)

new_embeddings = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(origin_embeddings,
                                             tf.expand_dims(indices, 1),
                                             indice_updated_embeddings)
tf.print(new_embeddings)
# [[1.1 2.2 3.3]
#  [1 2 3]
#  [7.7 8.8 9.9]
#  [4 5 6]]
```

In older versions where [`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update) is not available, you can do it like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

origin_embeddings = tf.constant([[1.1,2.2,3.3], 
                                 [4.4, 5.5, 6.6], 
                                 [7.7, 8.8, 9.9],
                                 [10.10, 11.11, 12.12]]) # 4 * 3
indice_updated_embeddings= tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
                                        [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]) #  2 * 3
indices = tf.constant([1, 3], dtype=tf.int32)

indices2 = tf.expand_dims(indices, 1)
s = tf.shape(origin_embeddings)
mask = tf.scatter_nd(indices2, tf.ones_like(indices2, tf.bool), [s[0], 1])
updates = tf.scatter_nd(indices2, indice_updated_embeddings, s)
new_embeddings = tf.where(mask, updates, origin_embeddings)
tf.print(new_embeddings)
# [[1.1 2.2 3.3]
#  [1 2 3]
#  [7.7 8.8 9.9]
#  [4 5 6]]
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for your help!!  The only small difference is that in Tensorflow 1.12.0, we need to squeeze the mask here, i.e., mask = tf.squeeze(mask, axis=-1). otherwise, it raise the error, "InvalidArgumentError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 1. Shapes are [4,3] and [4,1]. for 'Select_11' (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [4,1], [4,3], [4,3]." I really appreciate it!

Comment: @mgxs Huh, that's interesting, in more recent versions it requires you to have that additional dimension (I think it may be that they _finally_ added general broadcasting in `tf.where`).